# array is not getting values by using function in excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I think its basic question but i dont know that where i am lacking. Actually, what is wanted that pass array as an argument to function and function will return the array which can used in sub routine. I tried 2 methods, one is working fine but through 2nd, my array variable in sub routine is remaining empty. For reference, code is pasted with highlighted.

```
 Option Explicit
    
    Sub analysis()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim art1(), art11(), art2, art3() As Variant
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    'art11() = Sheet1.Range("D2:D12").Value
    ' art11 = arr() 'through this way, art11 is getting values from arrays by function arr() 
     art1() = Sheet2.Range("D2:D3000").Value
     art2 = arra(art1) ' art2 remain empty
    end sub
    ***********
    Function arr() As Variant
    
    Dim arry() As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
'Dim lastrow As Long

'' For having unique number of values from Column D in Sheet1

Dim d As Object, c, loc, uniq As Variant, i As Long, j, k, l, m, lr As Long
Dim a, b, cc, sht1, sht2, sht3 As Integer 'sht1, sht2 & sht3 are counter for counting artist numbers
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox lr
c = Sheet1.Range("D2:D" & lr)
For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
  d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i

Sheet1.Range("R2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
a = 2

Do While Sheet1.Cells(a, 18).Value <> ""
a = a + 1
Loop
a = a - 2
ReDim arry(a)
sht1 = 0
i = 1
Do While Sheet1.Cells(a, 18).Value <> ""

arry(i) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 18).Value
a = a + 1
sht1 = sht1 + 1
Loop
    

arr = arry()
    
    End Function
    ***************
    Function arra(arrt() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim arrtt() As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    'Dim lastrow As Long
    
    '' For having unique number of values from Column D in Sheet1
    
    Dim d As Object, c, loc, uniq As Variant, i As Long, j, k, l, m, lr As Long
    Dim a, b, cc, sht1, sht2, sht3 As Integer 'sht1, sht2 & sht3 are counter for counting artist numbers
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lr = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lr
    c = Sheet2.Range("D2:D" & lr)
    'MsgBox c
    For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
      d(c(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i
    
    Sheet2.Range("R2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
    a = 2
    
    Do While Sheet2.Cells(a, 18).Value <> ""
    a = a + 1
    Loop
    a = a - 2
    ReDim arrtt(a)
    sht1 = 0
    i = 1
    Do While Sheet2.Cells(a, 18).Value <> ""
    
    arrtt(i) = Sheet2.Cells(a, 18).Value
    a = a + 1
    sht1 = sht1 + 1
    Loop
    
    'a = a - 2
    'ReDim art1(a)
    'For k = 1 To a
    'art1(k) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 18).Value
    'a = a + 1
    'MsgBox art1(k)
    'Next k
    
    
    arrtt = arrt()
    
    ***** although arrt() have arrays with values in it and passing it to arrtt butby recalling the function in sub routine, it reman empty
    
    End Function
```

Comment: You have `Function arra(` but I don't see where you assign a value to `arra`. If you don't then  that function will never return anything.

Comment: Hi kindly check below where value has been assigned and passed to arra function 
                                                                                                                              
 art1() = Sheet2.Range("D2:D3000").Value
     art2 = arra(art1)

Comment: Passing a value to a function is not the same. You do it correctly in your other function, just before the End Function statement.

Answer (score 0):

### Get 1D or 2D Array of Unique Values in a Column Range

- The following shows how to write unique values of one column to another using a 1D or a 2D array.
- It also shows how to write the unique values from a 2D one-based one-column array to another 1D or 2D array.
- Note that this will fail if the column range contains only one cell and if all cells are empty or contain error values or contain blanks ("").

**The Code**

```
Sub TESTgetUniqueColumn()
    
    ' Calculate last row in column 'B'.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Write values from column 'D' to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    'Data = Sheet2.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Value
    Data = Sheet2.Cells(2, "D").Resize(LastRow - 2 + 1).Value
    
    ' Declare Result Array.
    Dim Result As Variant
    
    ' Note that 'Transpose' is restricted to maximally 65535 elements
    ' per dimension. Therefore when writing to ranges, it is preferred
    ' to use the 2D approach.
    
    ' 1D (Try with more than 65535 elements (unique values) to see how it fails.
    Result = getUniqueColumn(Data, True)
    Sheet2.Cells(2, "R").Resize(UBound(Result) - LBound(Result) + 1).Value _
      = Application.Transpose(Result)
    
    ' 2D
    Result = getUniqueColumn(Data) ' or 'getUniqueColumn(Data, False)'
    Sheet2.Cells(2, "S").Resize(UBound(Result, 1)).Value = Result

End Sub

Function getUniqueColumn(Data As Variant, _
                         Optional ByVal OneD As Boolean = False) As Variant
     
    ' Define Unique Dictionary.
    ' (Create a reference to the dictionary object.)
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Prepare for loop.
    Dim Key As Variant ' Current Value in Data Array
    Dim i As Long      ' Data Array Row Counter
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Unique Dictionary.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Key = Data(i, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) And Not IsEmpty(Key) Then
            dict(Key) = Empty
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    
    ' Write values from Unique Dictionary to 1D Result Array.
    If OneD Then
        Result = dict.Keys
    Else
        ' Prepare for loop.
        ReDim Result(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 1)
        i = 0
        ' Write values from Unique Dictionary to 2D Result Array.
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            i = i + 1
            Result(i, 1) = Key
        Next Key
    End If
    
    ' Write result.
    getUniqueColumn = Result

End Function
```

**Tips**

- Use descriptive names for variables.
- When declaring variables in one line, for each of them you have to have an `As`. And try to group them as you see fit.

**Corrections**

```
Sub analysis()

    Dim rng As Range
    ' Wrong declaration: here it doesn't matter, because if no As,
    ' then the varibles get declared as 'variant' anyway.
    'Dim art1(), art11(), art2, art3() As Variant
    Dim art1() As Variant, art11() As Variant, art2 As Variant, art3() As Variant
    ' Wrong declaration.
    'Dim i, j, k As Integer
    'Dim i As Integer, j  As Integer, k As Integer
    ' But nowadays we mostly do not use integer:
    Dim i As Long, j  As Long, k As Long
    'art11() = Sheet1.Range("D2:D12").Value
    ' art11 = arr() 'through this way, art11 is getting values from arrays by function arr()
    art1() = Sheet2.Range("D2:D30").Value ' Note: you're using 'Sheet2' here.
     ' art2 remains empty because the last line in the function is wrong.
    art2 = arra(art1)
End Sub

Function arra(arrt() As Variant) As Variant
    
    Dim arrtt() As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Dim lastrow As Long
    
    '' For having unique number of values from Column D in Sheet1
    ' Wrong declarations.
    'Dim d As Object, c, loc, uniq As Variant, i As Long, j, k, l, m, lr As Long
    'Dim a, b, cc, sht1, sht2, sht3 As Integer 'sht1, sht2 & sht3 are counter for counting artist numbers
    ' This is right ...
    'Dim d As Object, c As Object, loc As Object, uniq As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, lr As Long
    'Dim a As Long, b As Long, cc As Long, sht1 As Long, sht2 As Long, sht3 As Long  'sht1, sht2 & sht3 are counter for counting artist numbers
    ' ...but it is more readable to group by type...
    Dim d As Object, loc As Object
    Dim uniq As Variant, c As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, lr As Long
    ' ...or by any other logic:
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, cc As Long
    Dim sht1 As Long, sht2 As Long, sht3 As Long
    ' Not so good names i.e. sht, sheet, worksheet?
    
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'lr = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lr = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lr
    'c = Sheet2.Range("D2:D" & lr) ' readability:
    c = Sheet2.Range("D2:D" & lr).Value
    'MsgBox c ' This doesn't work if c is an array which it is, if lr > 1.
    For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
        d(c(i, 1)) = 1 ' I prefer empty: d(c(i, 1)) = Empty
    Next i
    
    'Sheet2.Range("R2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.Keys)
    ' To remove any confusion, either stick to Cells or Range:
    Sheet2.Cells(2, 18).Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.Keys)
    a = 2
    
    ' Here you are investigating how to write the result.
    ' Note that you already know the number of elements: 'd.Count'.
    
    Do While Sheet2.Cells(a, 18).Value <> ""
    a = a + 1
    Loop
    a = a - 2
    ReDim arrtt(a)
    sht1 = 0
    i = 1
    Do While Sheet2.Cells(a, 18).Value <> ""
    
    arrtt(i) = Sheet2.Cells(a, 18).Value
    a = a + 1
    sht1 = sht1 + 1
    Loop
    
    'a = a - 2
    'ReDim art1(a)
    'For k = 1 To a
    'art1(k) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 18).Value
    'a = a + 1
    'MsgBox art1(k)
    'Next k
    
    
    ' This is wrong (you forgot to change to 'arra'.
    'arrtt = arrt()
    arra = arrtt()
End Function
```